# Install 'JSONWebToken' library without cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Is there a way to install this [library](https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift) without cocoapods ? because when i install it with pod i get this error :

```
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!`
to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pods being used are: 
CryptoSwift and JSONWebToken
```

And when i add 'use_framewords!' i got error on the other libraries written with objective-c that use pod also

Here is my podfile :

```
source “https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git”
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
pod 'Instabug'
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: Add `use_frameworks!` to the particular Swift target, not the whole Podfile

Comment: Can you tell me what i need to type in podfile please

Answer (score 0):

- You can drag and drop the
  [link](https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift/tree/master/Sources)
  sources into your project. If you add the library in this way, you
  will update the library manually as you know.
- The second option is using cocoapods and solving the problem. When you use `use_frameworks!` cocoapods tries to convert the whole pods as framework, so the error should be in your bridging header. Try to import your frameworks in your files.

Comment: I did it but when i use JWT object i get "Use of unresolved identifier 'JWT'"

Comment: Can you add your podfile to the question?

Comment: Have you tried to add the library manually and remove the import from the header?

Comment: I don't have any import in header the files are written in swift